# Cannot implicity convert type System.Linq.Expression<System.Func<Object, bool>> to bool

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, expression

actually I have an Expression like this that work very well in the case of Linq to Entity

```
public static Expression<Func<Tender, bool>> GetPublic()
{
    var now = DateTime.Now.GetEasternStandardDateTime();

    return tender => tender.EndDate > DateTime.Now &&
                     tender.IsClosed == false && 
                     tender.IsCancel == false && 
                     tender.PrivacyLevelId == 1;
}
```

I can use the expression like this : `_repositoryObject.Where(GetPublic())` and I will get results.

But I cannot use the same expression when I have to do Linq to SQL pattern like this

```
var results = from t in Tenders
              where Tender.GetPublic()
              select t;
```

I have this error

> Cannot implicity convert type
>   System.Linq.Expression> to bool for Linq to
>   SQL

and I don't know why...

Karine

Comment: What line does this come up on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, I suspect you actually mean you can call it as:

```
_repositoryObject.Where(GetPublic())
```

It's important that you *call* the method to get the expression tree.

Your query expression is being converted into:

```
var results = Tenders.Where(t => Tender.GetPublic());
```

... which isn't what you're looking for. Basically, query expressions are translated into method calls using lambda expressions. You don't want that in this case, so you shouldn't use a query expression.

If you want to do other things with a query expression, you can always mix and match, e.g.

```
var results = from t in Tenders.Where(Tender.GetPublic())
              where t.SomeOtherProperty
              select t.SomethingElse;
```

Comment: If I don't want to mix and match, which alternative I have if I shouldn't use a query expression?

Comment: @Karine: Just use the extension methods (`Where`, `Select` etc) directly. Query expressions are just syntactic sugar anyway.

Answer (score -1):

If you change your method to take an `IQueryable<Tender>`, and return another `IQueryable<Tender>` where your criteria are added, then it might work.

```
public static IQueryable<Tender> AddPublicCriteria(this IQueryable<Tender> tenderQuery) {
    // I've omitted your call to DateTime.Now.GetEasternStandardDateTime()
    // since you do not use it.
    return tenderQuery
        .Where(tender => tender.EndDate > DateTime.Now &&
                         tender.IsClosed == false && 
                         tender.IsCancel == false && 
                         tender.PrivacyLevelId == 1
         );
}

var query = Tenders;                       // Original table or data-set
query = query.AddPublicCriteria();         // Add criteria
var results = query.ToList();              // Run query and put the results in a list
```

Comment: This is still going to require him to use this operation outside of query syntax.